# SQL Database: Update Table for

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql-server

I am working with an applications SQL database. On a daily basis, we receive a daily email with a list of employee User ID's that have been terminated. The script that is listed below is what we use to take the user ID (example: 12345), find it in the database and deactivate by changing the value. Part three is taking the user that was disabled, and places it into a separate table for audit purposes.

What I am looking to accomplish is

1) As you can see, I have to put the user ID in three locations. How can this be simplified to where I can just place one ID?

2) Not all users are in the application. When I see the "2 rows affected" I can see that that user ID has been disabled in the application. However, if the user is not even listed in the database, it gets written to the audit table `DailyTerminiations`. Any suggestions? I will be monitoring this post for questions you may have.

```
-- PART 1

UPDATE EnterpriseUser
SET IsActive = 0,  LastModDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE 
  IVRID = 12345;

-- PART 2

 UPDATE Staff
SET IsActive = 0,  LastModDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE StaffID = 
 (SELECT EnterpriseUserID 
  FROM EnterpriseUser 
  WHERE IVRID = 12345);

-- PART 3

INSERT INTO dbo.DailyTerminations (EnterpriseUserID, dateprocessed)
values (12345, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server. Then you need to provide a complete question. That means an explanation of what you are trying to do. Also you need to provide table definitions, sample data and desired output. This link does a great job of explaining that. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: SQLServer is NOT MySQL. They use different dialects and have different capabilities. Previously you were obviously using MySQL so why do you keep tagging SQL Server. Did your organization suddenly switch?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a trigger on the `EnterpriseUser` table. Basically, you can set it up so that whenever the table is updated, and the `is_active` field changes from `1` to `0`, the other tables are updated/added to accordingly.

Both [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) support triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes IVRID as a parameter, as for part 3 the problem you are having is you are inserting a value regardless of whether or not there are any updates to the previous tables. You could solve this by having your insert use the output of a select statement something like this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DailyTerminations (EnterpriseUserID, dateprocessed)
SELECT IVRID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM EnterpriseUser WHERE IsActive = 0 AND 
IVRID NOT IN (SELECT EnterpriseUserID FROM dbo.DailyTerminations  )
```

That will only create an entry for records in EnterpriseUser that have IsActive set to 0 and don't already exist in DailyTerminations

Hope this helps